# Add a blinking animation to a dotted border with CSS

Tags: css, css-animations, jquery-animate, border

I tried to make a animated dotted box border that moving back and forth, kind of blinking style. (Just like the third one with yellow border in the following link.)

[image: The example labeled 'fat border' has a border with a thick, dashed line where the yellow sections turn white and the white sections turn yellow after a every few seconds.]

http://there4.io/2013/01/03/jquery-animated-borders/

Yet, this is built with JavaScript. I am unable to change the dashed border into dotted style.

When I looked for a CSS solution, rather than moving discretely, most cases I found had a smooth animation.

eg. https://css-tricks.com/more-control-over-css-borders-with-background-image/

How can I achieve a blinking effect with a dotted border?

Comment: I am not clear what you want to achieve. Is it a continuous animation of a dashed border (as shown in the css-tricks link) but with fatter dashes (as shown in the first image)? What have you tried?

Comment: Im looking for a animation of dotted border blinking back and forth.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by blinking. Is that different from continuously moving?

Comment: sorry, Im not a native speaker. Its like a group of LED lights, shining alternately in each, making a visual effect of lights are moving back and forth as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out how to make it dotted (with actual circles) instead of dashed but you can make the animation blink instead of moving smoothly by using `steps` instead of `linear` for the animation timing. Linear does continuous animation at a consistent speed whereas the steps function puts stops in the animation:

```css
.box {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #333333, #333333 5px, transparent 5px, transparent 15px, #333333 15px), repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #333333, #333333 5px, transparent 5px, transparent 15px, #333333 15px), repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #333333, #333333 5px, transparent 5px, transparent 15px, #333333 15px), repeating-linear-gradient(270deg, #333333, #333333 5px, transparent 5px, transparent 15px, #333333 15px);
  background-size: 5px calc(100% + 15px), calc(100% + 15px) 5px, 5px calc(100% + 15px), calc(100% + 15px) 5px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: borderAnimation 1s infinite steps(2, end);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

@keyframes borderAnimation {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0, -15px 0, 100% -15px, 0 100%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 -15px, 0 0, 100% 0, -15px 100%;
  }
}

p {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<p>Most of the CSS is from the generator located at <a href="https://css-tricks.com/more-control-over-css-borders-with-background-image">More Control Over CSS Borders With background-image</a>/</p>
```

There are examples of the various timing functions at [MDN Web Docs: animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function).